# Conditionally format/style inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to come up with a manner to conditionally format (a simple background color) for an html table with results from an AngularJS controller. This would hopefully take place during the iterations of ng-repeat as it works through the elements in an array.

What I would like to accomplish is: whenever a function inside the controller returns true, the background or style is green, and when it is not it will be red.

LOOK FOR "BEGIN QUESTION" in a comment for the insertion point.

```
        <!-- PLAYER STATS TABLE -->
    <div id = "StatsListTable">
    <table border="1" style="width:80%">
    <tr> <!-- TODO: class="tr.pstats" -->
        <th>Character Name</th>
        <th>    
            <div ng-app="KIdash" ng-controller="controller">
            Total Matches: {{TotalMatchesFunc()}} :: {{GreaterWins()}}
            </div>
        </th>
        <th class="green">Wins</th>
        <th class="red">Losses</th>
    </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="ps in PlayerStats" class = "playerStatTable">
            <td>{{ps.name}}</td>
            <td>{{ps.matches}}</td>

            <!-- BEGIN QUESTION -->
            <!-- IF  {{GreaterWins()}}  make it green -->
            <!-- ELSE                   make it red   -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function() {
                if( controller.GreaterWins() )
                {
                    <th class="green">{{ps.wins}}</th>
                } else {
                    <th class="red">{{ps.wins}}</th>
                }
            }
            </script>
            <!-- END IF -->
            <td>{{ps.losses}}</td>
        </tr>
    <table>
    </div>
    <!-- END PLAYER STATS TABLE -->
```

Comment: Why did you update the original question? I would say keep the original question intact and add an edit with the solution if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by ng-class. Something like below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ps in PlayerStats" class = "playerStatTable">
      <td>{{ps.name}}</td>
      <td>{{ps.matches}}</td>
      <td ng-class="{'green': GreaterWins(),'red': !GreaterWins() }">{{ps.wins}}</td>                
      <td>{{ps.losses}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What an excellent answer! thanks you.  All my results are red, is there anything specific I need to do to guarantee that the GreaterWins() function is actually being used properly? do I need to refer to it as controller.GreaterWins() in this context?

Comment: you should not need to explicitly write `controller.GreaterWins()` because you are not using the controller as syntax. Is `GreaterWins()` funciton defined in the `controller` scope? and does it always return `false`?

Comment: When I replace the logical > comparison with either T or F it behaves as expected. So It seems I am just not comparing the values properly.

Comment: OH! I need to send in the ng-repeat $index to the GreaterWins() function in order to get the correct index of my array. Is this possible when using ng-class?

Comment: Yes you can do `<td ng-class="{'green': GreaterWins($index),'red': !GreaterWins($index) }">{{ps.wins}}</td>` OR you can even pass the actual element directly instead of the index like `<td ng-class="{'green': GreaterWins(ps),'red': !GreaterWins(ps) }">{{ps.wins}}</td> `

Comment: Thanks yet again. I wasn't able to get the method using the reference object to work (JS almost always passes by value right?)-- but passing in the index will work just fine for now.